# Terraform back-end to azure blob storage errors

Tags: azure, terraform

I have been using the below to successfully create a back-end state file for terraform in Azure storage, but for some reason its stopped working. I've recycled passwords for the storage, trying both keys and get the same error every-time

**backend.tf**

```
    terraform {
    backend "azurerm" {
        storage_account_name    = "terraformstorage"
        resource_group_name     = "automation"
        container_name          = "terraform" 
        key                     = "testautomation.terraform.tfstate"
        access_key              = "<storage key>"
    }
}
```

**Error returned**

> terraform init
>       Initializing the backend...
>       Successfully configured the backend "azurerm"! Terraform will automatically
>       use this backend unless the backend configuration changes.
>       Error refreshing state: storage: service returned error: StatusCode=403, ErrorCode=AuthenticationFailed, ErrorMessage=Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
>       RequestId:665e0067-b01e-007a-6084-97da67000000
>       Time:2018-12-19T10:18:18.7148241Z, RequestInitiated=Wed, 19 Dec 2018 10:18:18 GMT, RequestId=665e0067-b01e-007a-6084-97da67000000, API Version=, QueryParameterName=, QueryParameterValue=

Any ideas what im doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like your credentials are wrong. Can you try accessing the state file in the blob storage via another mechanism? Does Azure have a useful CLI tool you can use to test this?

Comment: hi ydaetskcoR, I can connect successfully to the storage using "Azure Storage Explorer" using storage account name and key, which is pretty much all that terraform uses. just to add to the confusion!

Comment: Another option to explore: make sure the container_name match the container used to generate the sas_token

Comment: I was deploying from Azure DevOps pipeline and created a service connection from the UI. I need to very the service connection again and enter my credentials. After that it works again.

Answer (score 18):

What worked for me is to delete the local .terraform folder and try again.

Answer (score 12):

Another problem can be time resolution.

I experienced those problems as well, tried all the above mentioned steps, but nothing helped.

What happened on my system (Windows 10, WSL2) was, that WSL lost its time sync and I was hours apart. This behaviour is described in https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4245.

For me it helped to

- get the appropriate time in WSL (`sudo hwclock -s`) and
- to reboot WSL

Hope, this will help others too.

Comment: This worked for me too. I only had to run hwclock -s, didn't need to reboot.  As soon as I saw the command I just had to roll my eyes. This was causing a problem in Apache Airflow for me too (solved by running the same command) - the cause, when my laptop goes to sleep, WSL takes a nap too, so looses time. I may just create a script in my bash profile as a temporary fix.

Comment: you can also run `wsl -d docker-desktop hwclock -s` in the host.

Comment: Thanks @MaxiPalle, that resolved it for me too. So many issues can be caused by the date sync issue. The worst part is it's intermittent, so I forgot about it. I appended `sudo hwclock -s` to my .profile file, just so I don't forget about this issue, but this terminal had been running overnight so I forgot.

Answer (score 8):

Here are few suggestions:

- Run: `terraform init -reconfigure`.
- Confirm your "terraform/backend" credentials.
- In case your Terraform contains some "[`azurerm_storage_account`/`network_rules`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/storage_account.html)" to allow certain IP addresses, or make sure you're connected to the right VPN network.
- If above won't work, run `TF_LOG=TRACE terraform init` to debug further.

Answer (score 2):

Please ensure you've been authenticated properly to Azure Cloud.

If you're running Terraform externally, re-run: `az login`.

If you're running Terraform on the instance, you can use [managed identities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?tabs=python), or by defining the following environmental variables:

```
ARM_USE_MSI=true
ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID=xxx-yyy-zzz
ARM_TENANT_ID=xxx-yyy-zzz
```

or just run `az login --identity`, then assign the right role ([`azurerm_role_assignment`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/role_assignment.html), e.g. "Contributor") and appropriate policies ([`azurerm_policy_definition`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/policy_assignment.html)).

See also:

- [Azure Active Directory Provider: Authenticating using Managed Service Identity](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azuread/guides/managed_service_identity.html).
- [Unable to programmatically get the keys for Azure Storage Account](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45448474/55075).

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue while setting the remote backend state to Azure StorageV2.
I was using SAS token to set the remote backend state. The token was generated using Terraform data provider (data "azurerm_storage_account_sas" ""). The SAS Token thus generated, was not working. So, I had to manually generate SAS token from Azure portal. That fixed the problem.

Answer (score -2):

There should a `.terraform` directory , where you are running the terraform init command from.

Remove `.terraform` or move it to Someotehr name. Next time terraform init runs , it will recreate that directory with new init.